# Another undefined reference to boost::system::generic

Tags: c++, boost

So I have my project completed - each module works fine on it's own, but when I try to link them together suddenly I can't because I get the following error:

```
obj/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
obj/main.o: In function `error_code':
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
obj/main.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
obj/asio.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Here is the command I'm using to compile:

```
[root@engdev GDAgent]# make all
g++ --std=c++0x -c main.cpp -o obj/main.o -g -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++/ -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/ -lmysqlpp -lnsl -lz -lm -lboost_thread -lboost_system -L/usr/lib64/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/
g++ --std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra obj/main.o obj/asio.o obj/dbase.o obj/serial.o -o GDAgent -g -L/obj-L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlpp -lm -lnsl -lz -I/usr/include/mysql++/ -lmysqlpp -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/ -lboost_thread  -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_system-mt
```

This is my makefile:

```
all: GDAgent
        g++ --std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra obj/main.o obj/asio.o obj/dbase.o obj/serial.o -o GDAgent -g -L/obj-L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlpp -lm -lnsl -lz -I/usr/include/mysql++/ -lmysqlpp -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/ -lboost_thread  -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_system-mt

GDAgent: include/serial.h  include/dbase.h
        g++ --std=c++0x -c main.cpp -o obj/main.o -g -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++/ -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/ -lmysqlpp -lnsl -lz -lm -lboost_thread -lboost_system -L/usr/lib64/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/

dbase.o: include/dbase.cpp include/dbase.h include/serial.h
        g++ --std=c++0x -o obj/dbase.o -c include/dbase.cpp -g -I/usr/include/mysql++ -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/ -lmysqlpp -lnsl -lz -lm -lboost_thread -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_system

serial.o: include/serial.cpp include/serial.h include/dbase.h
        g++ --std=c++0x  -o obj/serial.o  -c include/serial.cpp -g -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/ -lmysqlpp -lnsl -lz -lm -lboost_thread -lboost_system -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/

asio.o:  include/asio.cpp include/serial.h include/dbase.h
        g++ --std=c++0x  -o obj/asio.o -c include/asio.cpp -g -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/ -lmysqlpp -lnsl -lz -lm -lboost_thread -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -I/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_system
```

I've been searching through solutions here, and thus far the solutions I've found either I'm doing them incorrectly or they simply aren't the cause of my problem. (e.g. moving -lboost_system-mt to the end, etc.)

So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your library path(s) with `-L` instead of `-I`

```
-L/usr/lib/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_system-mt
```

`-I` is for header include paths.